# jQuery: when .animate.slideUp finished

Tags: jquery, function

I need to execute something (let's say an alert) after animate AND slideup are finished.
With my current method, the alert is fired after animate and after slideup.

That's the code I use:

```
$(this).siblings()
       .find("ul")
       .animate({width:'1px'}, 1)
       .slideUp(1, function(){
             alert("Handler for called.");
       });
```

By the way -is there an better way to set back width to original 1px and to "undo" slideDown than with the the way I did it above?

Thank you!

Comment: So you'd like to fire an alert two times, one for each animation ?

Comment: can you share the html and also how this method is executed, this will execute the callback after `slideUp`

Comment: If you are getting more than 1 alert it is because ` $(this).siblings()` might be returning more than 1 element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#nav li:has(ul)").hover(function () {
        $(this).siblings().find("ul").stop(true, true).animate({
            width: '1px'
        }, 1).slideUp(1);
        $(this).find("ul").slideDown().animate({
            width: '300px'
        }, 350);

    });

});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/93reJ/13/)

Comment: Thanks for your help - it also fires twice in my example; I guess it is because there are two siblings. I uploaded it to show what's the problem. Instead of alert I use slideDown and animate now.
I don't want two submenus shown at the same time, so when there is one submenu open all other submenus should be "removed" with the function, AFTERWARDS the new current submenu should show up.

Here's the link: http://jsfiddle.net/hausmaster/93reJ/12/

Thanks!

Comment: See if updated answer fit your needs otherwise i don't see what you are looking for

Comment: May I ask one more question? I tried to combine this with HoverIntent and a new problem occurred. When you move the mouse from "Aktuelles" to "Menüpunkt 3" and back very fast (so that the animation can't finish), the Submenu doesn't appear anymore. I can't figure out why. http://jsfiddle.net/hausmaster/93reJ/15/
Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Sorry, i don't know the plugin you are using and don't have time to check in source code what's going wrong. You should open a new question more specific to the use of this plugin. BTW, still consider to accept this answer as it was answering your previous issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the callback also for the animate function:

Living demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gawuQ/

```
 var myList = $(this).siblings().find("ul");

 myList.animate({
     width: '1px'
 }, 1, function () {
       myList.slideUp(1, function () {
         alert("Handler for called.");
     });
 });
```

Living demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gawuQ/

Comment: Thank you very much - I specified the problem in the answer from "roasted".